# Algebraic and Analytic definition of monotony

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions, monotone-operator-theory

I have a hard time seeing the relationship between a monotone operator and monotone function.

A monotone function (increasing in this case) in real analysis is defined as:

Let $f:I \mapsto \Bbb R $ where I is an interval of $\Bbb R$ is monotone if: $\forall x,y \in \Bbb R$ $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$.
The notion of monotony can be extended to that of partially ordered sets (adds more conditions to it, but the spirit of the property remains the same).

A monotone operator on the other hand is defined as:

Let $f:X \mapsto P(X)$ a valued set operator on a hilbert space X.

$f$ is monotone if $\forall (x,y)\in G(f),\forall (x',y')\in G(f)\langle y-y'|x-x'\rangle \geq 0$

Is the second a generalization of the first?

A simple example using $\Bbb R$ with the standard scalar product shows that the two properties are related:
let $f:\Bbb R \mapsto\Bbb R$ a function. Let $x, y \in\Bbb R$.

$$\langle f(x) - f(y) | x - y\rangle = (f(x) - f(y))(x-y) \geq 0 \iff \operatorname{sign}(f(x) - f(y)) = \operatorname{sign}(x - y)$$

More generally, take any real valued increasing function and extend it to $R^n$, this equivalence holds up pretty well.

The second definition seems to come from an entirely different field, and I have the feeling that they are not that equivalent (the order relation is not at all used in convex optimization to my knowledge).